# msgbox vb.net shows windowsappication3 instead of application name

Tags: vb.net, forms, msgbox

I am trying to figure out why the default name for my MsgBox in vb.net is stuck as WindowsApplication3. I understand that it is the name of the default program that I started with, but I have looked in options and have not been able to find where to change this. I can change it separately per MsgBox, but I want to change the default as well. Any idea on where that is?

[image: Picture of MsgBox]

Comment: My Project - Application - Assembly name

Comment: Thank you @LarsTech